# How can I install IBM Cplex

Tags: macos, cplex

How can I install Cplex to my macbook? I have already tried to install it but when I installed it, it couldn't have opened. It wants Java 6 runtime but it's already installed.

Answer (score 0):

in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/Optimization_Studio/topics/COS_installing.html

you may read

```
Installing on Macintosh

    Double-click to unzip the cos_installer <version>-osx.zip
    Double-click the cplex_studio<version>-osp.app and the installer guides you through the installation.

On Mac, the default installation location of IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio is:

/Applications/CPLEX_Studio[edition]<version>

IDE
You can launch the IDE by either

    opening launchpad and clicking the oplide icon in the "CPLEX_Studio<version>" app, or
    by launching the oplide.app from the /Applications/CPLEX_Studio<version>/opl/oplide folder.

More information

For more information on CPLEX features on the Mac platforms, see

/Applications/CPLEX_Studio<version>/doc/html/en-US/documentation.html
```

and at https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=1e453851-3c50-4c72-83a9-8c7f05df8810&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer#bm1e453851-3c50-4c72-83a9-8c7f05df8810

you can read that you could try switching to light mode